# Is there a way to include multiple SecureRoutes in React?

Tags: node.js, security, routes, okta

I have a working auth integration into a React app with Okta, and I have 2 routes that require authentication in order to render. The authentication part is working as expected, however, it appears that the login controls are duplicated and the Sign In button is placed in the wrong position. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

```
<Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth} restoreOriginalUri={restoreOriginalUri} onAuthRequired={onAuthRequired}>
            
  <Header/>
  <Route path='/' exact={true} component={Home}/>            
  <Route path='/Login' exact={true} component={Login}/> 

  <SecureRoute path='/Secure1' component={Secure1}/>
  <SecureRoute path='/Secure2' component={Secure2}/>

  <Route path='/callback' component={LoginCallback}/>
</Security>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it has nothing to do with `oktaAuth`. Issue was on the CSS side, I had an extra Form defined there. After solving that issue, I'm able to use `SecureRoutes` flawlessly.